# Performance Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have maven project, with the help of which I am trying to execute a jmx file, running JMeter with (jmeter-maven-plugin). I have the following console output

```
  P E R F O R M A N C E    T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Invalid value detected for <postTestPauseInSeconds>.  Setting pause to 0...
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] Executing test: ZawyaJmeterTest.jmx
[INFO] Writing log file to: D:\tools\jmeter_examples\Example\jmeter-maven-example\target\jmeter\logs\ZawyaJmeterTest.jmx.log
[INFO] Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'D:\tools\jmeter_examples\Example\jmeter-maven-example\target\jmeter\testFiles\ZawyaJmeterTest.jmx', missing class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration' : No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration'
```

I thought in order to fix the issue  `org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration` I tried to add SampleSaveConfiguration class in dependency

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But It did not helped in fact. Than I looked for problem `No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration'`, but in class `SampleSaveConfiguration` I found field `private boolean sentBytes;`
I do not know in what way search such issue.

When running JMeter test locally it is fine -

```
d:\tools\jmeter_examples\Example\jmeter-maven-example>jmeter -n -t D:\tools\jmeter_examples\Example\jmeter-maven-example\src\test\jmeter\ZawyaJmeterTest.jmx -l D:\tools\jmeter_examples\Example\jmeter-maven-example\target\jmeter\results\ZawyaJmeterTest.jtl
    Writing log file to: d:\tools\jmeter_examples\Example\jmeter-maven-example\jmeter.log
    Created the tree successfully using D:\tools\jmeter_examples\Example\jmeter-maven-example\src\test\jmeter\ZawyaJmeterTest.jmx
    Starting the test @ Wed Nov 30 17:26:53 EET 2016 (1480519613563)
    Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
    Tidying up ...    @ Wed Nov 30 17:27:07 EET 2016 (1480519627819)
    ... end of run
```

Does anybody faced such issue? Or recommend some ways of the decision, please!!!

Comment: You are trying to specify the JMeter version wrong, see https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Specifying-JMeter-Version

Answer (score 0):

It seems that current version of jmeter-maven-plugin (2.0.3) lags a bit behind the JMeter versions (current is 3.1).

I had absolutely the same exception when tried to run my 3.1-versioned jmx. But, when I've recreated the jmx with JMeter GUI of version 2.13, it worked well with jmeter-maven-plugin of version 2.0.3.

Probably it is worth to downgrade your working version of JMeter.

Comment: Version 2.1.0 is now out, which defaults to JMeter 3.1

Comment: You can also specify the version of JMeter you want the plugin to use, so you don't need to wait for a new release to use the latest version of JMeter: https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Specifying-JMeter-Version

Answer (score 0):

Last version 2.6.0 of [jmeter-maven-plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) now support last version of JMeter 3.3 and is now maintained by 2 persons among which one committer of Apache JMeter project so it now tightly follows JMeter releases.

See this on how to configure it:

- https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterMavenPlugin
- https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Basic-Configuration

All your issues should be fixed.